# How to configure spring boot application environment variables value in Azure DevOps

Tags: spring-boot, azure-devops

## application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWPRD}
```

> Above is the application.properties file of my project. How I can
> configure all these values dynamically. for eg. ${DB_URL} should take
> the value dynamically depending upon the environments(Test, Prod) in azure pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use repleace variable extension like this [one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

After installing it you should add a task

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/*.config
      **/*.json => outputs/*.json
```

please configure properly target files.

Also default setting used this syntax:

```
spring.datasource.url=#{DB_URL}#
```